# How to parcel PagedList<>?

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

I've got `data class` that contains variable of type PagedList?. This class needs to implement `Parcelable` because I want to save its state inside my `Bundle`.

How can I parcel objects of this type? `@Parcelize` doesn't help. How can I write a custom `Parceler` for `PagedList`? Or maybe there's another way by some kind of object wrapping?

Comment: you can't . If you want to save `the state` use `Room`

Answer (score 0):

You just have to give annotation `@Parcelize`  on the class and extend that class to `Parcelable` and if any property of that class having Another class then that class also should be `Parcelable`.

And if you getting some error or something wrong then please let me know in comments.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `@Parcelize` annotation but currently, I have a problem with the class that isn't created by me. I'm using `Paging library` which is part of `Android Jetpack`. I can't extend it by `Parcelable`. I'm getting an error `Type is not directly supported by `Parelize`."

Comment: Yeah. You cannot make Parcelable Class if it is not a model class. Can you please provide a screenshot or more detail about which class you are trying to make Parcelable.